# Error in Producer consumer without Synchronization program

Tags: java

I’m getting an error in the following code. Can someone help me?

```
class Q
    {
        int n;
        synchronized int get()
        {
            System.out.println("Got n :"+n);
            return n;
        }
        synchronized void put(int n)
        {
            this.n = n;
            System.out.println("Put n :"+n);
        }
    }

class Producer implements Runnable
{
    Q q1;
    Producer(Q q)
    {
        this.q1 = q;
        new Thread(this).start(); 
    }
    public void run()
    {
        int i =0;
        q1.put(i++);
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    Q q1;
    Consumer(Q q)
    {
        this.q1 = q;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        q1.get();
    }
}

class ProducerConsumerWithoutSync
{
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {
        Q q = new Q();
        new Producer(q);
        new Consumer(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Never tell to another programmer that you're getting an error without saying what the error is !

Comment: ProducerConsumerWithoutSync.java:7: missing return statement
        }
        ^
1 error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going wrong with you. I ported your code to ideone. https://ideone.com/HdA0sP

As you can see, it works perfectly. If you think that the value should be 1, then you are wrong.

You are doing `q1.put(i++);` this code returns i and then adds one to it. If you want to return the value after adding 1 to it, you should use `++i`

Answer (score 0):

About design of `Q`;
Synchronization is done in `Q`, with an assumption; `put` will be called before `get`. But only thing guaranteed in your code is; `run` method of `Producer` will run first.

Imagine, calculation in Producer is heavy (things which should be done before calling `put`), more likely `get` will be called first.

I think it has a very low possibility, but in the current situation, still it may happen.

This is Producer's `run` (assuming you fixed `++i` as mentioned by Kevin);
`> javap -c Producer`

```
public void run();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: aload_0       
       3: getfield      #15                 // Field q1:LQ;
       6: iinc          1, 1
       9: iload_1       
      10: invokevirtual #31                 // Method Q.put:(I)V
      13: return        
}
```

This is Consumer's `run` method;

```
public void run();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #15                 // Field q1:LQ;
       4: invokevirtual #31                 // Method Q.get:()I
       7: pop           
       8: return
```

As you see, there are things to do, before Q.get/set is called.

You can use `wait` in get and `notifyAll` in `put` to fix it.